# WatchKit super.awakeWithContext() and super.willActivate()

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit

I am wondering about if I should set up my objects before or after these methods in the WatchKit, and why?

I think I saw a WWDC video saying it should be before super.willActivate(), but I can not remember which one it is.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is following:

```
override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {

    // Call super
    super.awakeWithContext(context)

    // Do whatever you want
    self.doInterfaceConfiguration()
}
```

In this method, you should do primarily interface configuration. The main reason behind doing configuration here is that in that point you can be sure that all your outlets are connected to objects and controller itself is properly configured. More about those methods can be found in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/).

Edit: To answer your second question about willActivate() method, this is taken from documentation:

> The willActivate method lets you know when your interface is about to
>   become visible on Apple Watch. Use that method to make any last minute
>   updates to your controls or to start times or other tasks. (Do not use
>   it for your primarily initialization.) Use the corresponding
>   didDeactivate method to perform any final cleanup.

Comment: What about before or after super.willActivate()?

Comment: In general, you should always call `super.willDoSomething()` (like you would in normal controllers, fe. `super.willAppear()`) before you execute your own code. Not doing so might result in some of your changes being overridden or you ending up in inconsistent states

Comment: Except for super.init(). We should usually call super.init() in the end of init() function.